# Insert anchor tag before image tag jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make image clickable and for this I want to wrap image within anchor tag, following is the code I tried but its generating anchor tag after image tag

This is the HTML code

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
 jQuery('.fancybox-inner').append('<a href="#" class="new-img-holder"></a>');   
 jQuery('.fancybox-image').appendTo('new-img-holder');
});
```

```html
<div class="fancybox-outer">
  <div class="fancybox-inner" style="overflow: visible; width: 640px; height: 463px;">
    <img class="fancybox-image" src="cine-sudarshan.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "I want to wrap image within anchor tag" - you did not wrap the image in an anchor tag (O.o) . Why not use `document.getElementById('fancybox-outer')` and then complete the link in there? When you append in jquery for an action you then have to bind to that event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the HTML inside the container, add the anchor tag and append it again.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var html = jQuery('.fancybox-inner').html()
  var newHtml = '<a href="#" class="new-img-holder">' + html + '</a>'
  jQuery('.fancybox-outer').empty().html(newHtml);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fancybox-outer">
  <div class="fancybox-inner" style="overflow: visible; width: 640px; height: 463px;">
    <img class="fancybox-image" src="cine-sudarshan.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Just use [wrap](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) function for this like below:

```
$("img.fancybox-image").wrap('<a href="#" />');
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/7hcqbsmm/)

Answer (score 1):

I would use jQuery [`.wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) function for this as follow.

`$( ".fancybox-image" ).wrap( "<a href='LINK_TO_NAVIGATE'></a>" );`

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the anchor to go *before*, use jQuery's [`.prepend`](https://api.jquery.com/prepend/) or [`.prependTo`](https://api.jquery.com/prependTo/) methods.  If you want to truly wrap it, then use jQuery's [`.wrap`](https://api.jquery.com/wrap/) method.

(Or, perhaps the more correct answer is Sytor's -- which is to just do it directly in your markup.)

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(".fancybox-image").wrap('<a href="#" class="new-img-holder"></a>');
```

Comment: You should use single quotes inside wrap function.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code. It's easy if you use jquery wrap function.

```js
  jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
                $(".fancybox-image").wrap('<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="alert(\'clicked anchor tag\')" class="new-img-holder"></a>');
                //jQuery('.fancybox-inner').wrap('<a href="#" class="new-img-holder"></a>');
                //jQuery('.fancybox-image').wrap('new-img-holder');
            });
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <div class="fancybox-outer">
            <div class="fancybox-inner" style="overflow: visible; width: 640px; height: 463px;">
                <img class="fancybox-image" src="http://imgsv.imaging.nikon.com/lineup/lens/zoom/normalzoom/af-s_dx_18-140mmf_35-56g_ed_vr/img/sample/sample1_l.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: When you click on Image it will give you alert which will prove that image is inside the anchor tag